# How to sync table from AOT of MS Dynamic AX to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I set up Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express on my Computer And I want to sync (copy) data from some table inside AOT of Microsoft Dynamic AX 2012 -R3. Do you have any idea to connect them and copy data ?

Comment: Where is the AX database located? It sounds like whatever you're trying to do is for some sort of development/experimenting/analysis? If it is, then just skip the AOT and do SQL to SQL. Why are you using SQL Express instead of the same SQL instance that AX is installed on? Sounds dicey...

Comment: Simply I developed another software which use SQL Express As database . So that I have to get data from AX and store on SQL Express also then These data is used  on my Software

Comment: So can you do `SQL` to `SQL Express`? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005